# Scanning no: of characters of a file and write it that file itself

Tags: bash, shell

I have to scan the no of characters in a file and to write to that file itself with a hardcoded way like 99|EOF|.
for eg: if a text file : test.txt is having abcd as text in it. count will be 4.
So i need to write a next line in same file ie: test.txt like 99|EOF|4
Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo "99|EOF|$(wc -m <file.txt)" >>file.txt
```

The command `wc -m <file.txt` will give the number of characters in the file and then we are putting the desired formatted string at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
wc -m test.txt | awk '{print "99|EOF|"$1}' >> test.txt
```

Explanation:

```
NAME
       wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file

...    
       -m, --chars
              print the character counts
```

`awk '{print "99|EOF|"$1}'` prints `99|EOF|<char counted>` and `>>` is used to append output by above command to `test.txt`